# ASP.NET - Strange case of inexplicable 404 error

Tags: asp.net

We are having a very strange problem on one particular web server (we do not have direct access to the web server, only FTP access).

Our ASP.NET application displays a dataset into a standard GridView. One of the columns in the GridView is a basic template column, with a link redirecting to another page - passing few parameters.

One of the parameters is `EmployeeName` - and the following page uses that parameter to set a label.

ON this particular web server (WEBSERVER1 in this example)... the resulting link generates an error 404 (page not found)

`https://WWW.WEBSERVER1.COM/Customer_011B.aspx?WeekEnding=1/21/2012&GUID=n.a.&EmployeeName=Knutson-Haushalter, Kathleen&ReportToName=Mary Jo Eayrs&Assignment_Id=123772`

On another web server (WEBSERVER2 in this example)... the resulting link properly opens the page.

`http://WWW.WEBSERVER2.COM/Customer_011B.aspx?WeekEnding=1/21/2012&GUID=n.a.&EmployeeName=Knutson-Haushalter, Kathleen&ReportToName=Mary Jo Eayrs&Assignment_Id=123772`

(unfortunately the links above are not rendered correctly

Yes, I am aware that WEBSERVER1 is running under SSL - but am not sure why this would make a difference.

Now, we have verified that the page Customer_011B.aspx is indeed present on WEBSERVER1.

Here comes the puzzle:

If we only remove the EmployeeName parameter, the page displays correctly. All database operations are performed correctly, etc. The only "problem" is that the EmployeeName is not reported in the target label.

In other words:

This DOES NOT work and all we get is error 404

`https://WWW.WEBSERVER1.COM/Customer_011B.aspx?WeekEnding=1/21/2012&GUID=n.a.&EmployeeName=Knutson-Haushalter, Kathleen&ReportToName=Mary Jo Eayrs&Assignment_Id=123772`

This DOES work and we get to the page and we retrieve all the needed data.

`https://WWW.WEBSERVER1.COM/Customer_011B.aspx?WeekEnding=1/21/2012&GUID=n.a.&ReportToName=Mary Jo Eayrs&Assignment_Id=123772`

Just in case you are wondering, the only parameter needed by our data access layer is that Assignment_Id number.

Also, note that I enclosed the links in double quotes... so that they would render properly...

Comment: This is strange. Maybe the page/code is different on webserver1? What are IIS logs saying for 404?

Comment: Does this work: "https://WWW.WEBSERVER1.COM/Customer_011B.aspx?WeekEnding=1/21/2012&GUID=n.a.&EmployeeName=Knutson-Haushalter%2C Kathleen&ReportToName=Mary Jo Eayrs&Assignment_Id=123772"

ok so it won't format in comment. I replaced the comma with the html escape code equivalent %2C

Comment: The two things that stand out in the URL with `EmployeeName` - the dash (check that it's actually a hyphen and not a n-dash), and the comma. Comma is a reserved character in URL's, meaning it may work, but it may not - depending on the web server and the server's settings. Might be the problem.

Comment: Does webserver1 work if you remove the dash between Knutson and Haushalter? If so maybe try using UrlEncode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Comment: Very much a side note, but if you were to just pass the two employee ids (assuming that you have some sort of identifier in your datasource) and load the name on your page, would this not get around your issue?

Comment: Check out what the IIS versions are on each of the servers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UrlEncode` and `UrlDecode` to place the parametres on your url. I see that you use spaces and slash and commas. Parametres with slash/space/comma and other invalid url characters maybe cut or change by enabled url filter on one of the iis server.